How to use compareCluster in ClusterProfiler for Multiple GSEA Comparisons in a single GSEA analysis?
I am new to using compareCluster and just want to double check - the input for compareCluster can be DESeq2 results by using both the log2fc and Entrez id: is that correct?
And one can basically just order the log2fc and Entrez id in descending order (from greatest to lowest log2fc) and extract the entire gene list?... or just the significant ones (ex: <0.05 padj) ... or does it not matter?
So, say I have 4 DESeq results/comparisons:
Treatment A vs. control,
Treatment B vs. control,
Treatment C vs. control,
Treatment D vs. control
For compareCluster, I would:

Take the DESeq results for each comparison and convert gene id/symbol to Entrez id
Extract entrez id and log2fc values and order them in descending order; and
Pull just the entrez id and save it as a list (I would then have, for example: GeneListA, GeneListB, GeneListC and GeneListD).

Then, I would save these 4 gene lists into a single list (e.g., myGeneList) and use it as input for compareCluster?
My ultimate goal is to run gene set enrichment and over representation analysis and being able to compare and visualize the results "all together", instead of running one for each DESeq comparisons, in a dotplot or barplot to investigate the GO terms/KEGG pathways that each treatment has in common/uncommon.
Clarification is much appreciated! I've been searching online for details as to what the "gene list" should look like but haven't found anything that can answer my question.
Thank you.
